# how can I Enabling Remote MySQL in google cloud?

Tags: mysql, cloud

I installed a phpmyadmin in google cloud and have a database in phpmyadmin.

now I want to Enabling this database to Remote MySQL. then my other hosting server can connect this database.

if there is a Cpanel, it is simply add host or ip in the Remote MySQL. but now only
 phpmyadmin, how to do tyhat? thanks

Comment: a), you probably can't. b) its only really sensible to run mysql in the same LAN that you are connecting from for security and performance reasons.

Comment: then why if cpanel installed, it is easy to do that?

Comment: i want to do this : https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/

Comment: Google most likely don't allow access to their hosted MySQL from outside a cloud. Have you tied? What error do you get. I want a pony but we don't always get what we want.

Comment: it must be ok. dont know how to do only